# Deleting files which start with a name Python

Tags: python

I have a few files I want to delete, they have the same name at the start but have different version numbers. Does anyone know how to delete files using the start of their name?

```
Eg.
version_1.1
version_1.2
```

Is there a way of delting any file that starts with the name version?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to delete files matching `version_1.*`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
import os, glob
for filename in glob.glob("mypath/version*"):
    os.remove(filename)
```

Substitute the correct path (or `.` (= current directory)) for `mypath`. And make sure you don't get the path wrong :)

This will raise an Exception if a file is currently in use.

Comment: The exception is only raised on windows. Deleting files work a little different on Unices.

Answer (score 19):

If you really want to use Python, you can just use a combination of [os.listdir()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir), which returns a listing of all the files in a certain directory, and [os.remove()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.remove).

I.e.:

```
my_dir = # enter the dir name
for fname in os.listdir(my_dir):
    if fname.startswith("version"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(my_dir, fname))
```

However, as other answers pointed out, you really don't have to use Python for this, the shell probably natively supports such an operation.

Answer (score 4):

In which language?

In bash (Linux / Unix) you could use:

```
rm version*
```

or in batch (Windows / DOS) you could use:

```
del version*
```

If you want to write something to do this in Python it would be fairly easy - just look at the documentation for regular expressions.

edit:
just for reference, this is how to do it in Perl:

```
opendir (folder, "./") || die ("Cannot open directory!");
@files = readdir (folder);
closedir (folder);

unlink foreach (grep /^version/, @files);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
os.chdir("/home/path")
for file in os.listdir("."):
    if os.path.isfile(file) and file.startswith("version"):
         try:
              os.remove(file)
         except Exception,e:
              print e
```

Comment: os.path.isfile(file) return False

Answer (score 1):

The following function will remove all files and folders in a directory which start with a common string:

```
import os
import shutil

def cleanse_folder(directory, prefix):
    for item in os.listdir(directory):
        path = os.path.join(directory, item)
        if item.startswith(prefix):
            if os.path.isfile(path):
                os.remove(path)
            elif os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, item)):
                shutil.rmtree(path)
            else:
                print("A simlink or something called {} was not deleted.".format(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import re
directory = "./uploaded"
pattern = "1638813371180"
files_in_directory = os.listdir(directory)
filtered_files = [file for file in files_in_directory if ( re.search(pattern,file))]
for file in filtered_files:
    path_to_file = os.path.join(directory, file)
    os.remove(path_to_file)
```

Comment: Won't this list also files that just contains this pattern? Probably using `.startswith(patter)` may be enough.