# Deleting older files that start with same name

Tags: python

I'm storing query-content in CSV-files. Before storing I want to delete all queries that start with the same name (f.e. "DF_Tripheader") that are from an older date. I used this as inspiration: "[Deleting files which start with a name Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012670/deleting-files-which-start-with-a-name-python)" but it doesnt work. I dont get an error but the older files also don't get deleted. Can anyone help me out here?

```
Queries = {"DF_TripHeader":DF_TripHeader,"DF_AM":DF_AM}
SQL_Folder = 'SQL_RawData/'

def get_data_from_sql():
    if not os.path.exists(SQL_Folder):
        os.makedirs(SQL_Folder)

   for Query_Name, Query in Queries.items():
     if not os.path.exists(SQL_Folder + '{}_'.format(Query_Name) + str(date.today()) +'.csv'):

        for filename in glob.glob('"' + SQL_Folder + Query_Name + '*"'): #here is the problem
            os.remove(filename)

        Query_CSV = pd.read_sql_query(Query,Conn_SQL)
        Query_CSV.to_csv(SQL_Folder + '{}_'.format(Query_Name) + str(date.today()) +'.csv')
        print('{} downloaded successful'.format(Query_Name))
    else:
        print('Already downloaded {}'.format(Query_Name))

get_data_from_sql()
```

EDIT: Kishor Pawar managed to solve the problem, thanks a lot!!

```
Queries = {"SQL_TripHeader":SQL_TripHeader,"SQL_AM":SQL_AM}
SQL_Folder = 'SQL_RawData/'
Date = str(date.today())


def get_data_from_sql():
if not os.path.exists(SQL_Folder):
    os.makedirs(SQL_Folder)

for Query_Name, Query in Queries.items():
    if not os.path.exists(SQL_Folder + '{}_'.format(Query_Name) + Date +'.csv'):
        for filename in glob.glob("{0}{1}*".format(SQL_Folder, Query_Name)):
            try:
                os.remove(filename)
            except:
                print('x')
        Query_CSV = pd.read_sql_query(Query,Conn_SQL)
        Query_CSV.to_csv(SQL_Folder + '{}_'.format(Query_Name) + Date +'.csv')
        print('{} downloaded successful'.format(Query_Name))
    else:
        print('Already downloaded {}'.format(Query_Name))
get_data_from_sql()
```

Comment: You seem to have a path issues, print all the paths for debugging, you should get where your code is wrong.

Comment: Everything in the code works perfectly fine except the file deletion. When I print the path for this `'"' + SQL_Folder + Query_Name + '*"'` I get `"SQL_RawData/DF_TripHeader*"`. Which is exactly the same format as in the link I provided. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. From your comments, I found following.

Your error is `"SQL_RawData/DF_TripHeader*"`, which actually should have been `"SQL_RawData/DF_TripHeader/*" #notice the slash before *`.

`glob.glob` returns a list of paths matching passed in `pathname`. I don't know what it returned when you passed `"SQL_RawData/DF_TripHeader*"`. But it would return all the filenames when you pass `"SQL_RawData/DF_TripHeader/*"`.

Also, note that `glob.glob` would return a list of `filenames`. You need to pass the actual path to `os.remove`

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me, really appreciated! If I use this `"SQL_RawData/DF_TripHeader/*"` isn't the extra "/" indicating a new subfolder? The files are actually directly stored in the Folder `SQL_RawData`. They are named (for example) `DF_TripHeader_2018-12-05.csv`, so there would be no need for an extra "/". I'm really kind of lost here, since it feels like it should work, but it doesnt.

Comment: Got it.

Please try printing filename just before `os.remove` statement. That would exactly tell you what is being removed. 

Thanks for upvote.

Comment: Also, note that `glob.glob` would return a list of `filenames`. You need to pass the actual path to `os.remove`

Comment: I actually cant print the filename since my code never executes anything in the for 
loop (because it probably doesn't recognize the path?). I'm new to python so maybe it doesn't work like this, but isn't `filename` just kind of a dummy variable to loop through the files in the folder?

Comment: ok, do one thing. before for loop, print os.getcwd(). And then check `SQL_RawData/` is in the same directory.

Comment: From what I can see, the path is correct `C:\Users\*\PycharmProjects\Route Optimization`. This is also where the file is stored.

Comment: Then, you should check the ownership of the files you want to remove. match onwership of files and ownership of runnig program

Comment: I'm the only user of this Computer (its a private one), is it possible that I'm not the owner of the file?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Right click, go to properties and check ownership and visibility of files you want to remove.

Comment: Thanks again for being so patient with my questions. I checked the files now and for all of them I am the owner and have all the rights.

Comment: You said, statement in your for loop is not getting executed. that means `glob.glob` is rerurning `0` elements. Print `glob.glob('"' + SQL_Folder + Query_Name + '*"')` before for loop. you should receive the list of file names.

Comment: Just did what you suggested but it returned only `[]`. But when I print `'"' + SQL_Folder + Query_Name + '*"'` alone it returns `"SQL_RawData\DF_TripHeader*"`. Which according to me is the correct filepath.

Comment: that path would only work, if your current working directory is one above `SQL_RawData`. You pass the absolute path to `glob.glob`. and It will work.

Comment: Like this: `for filename in glob.glob("'C:\\Users\\\micha\\PycharmProjects\\" + SQL_Folder + Query_Name + "*'"):` ?

When I try this, the list stays empty (`[]`).

Comment: And please use single `forward` slashes in paths.

Comment: It contains two normal CSV files that are created with the code you see above. They are named `DF_AM_2018-12-05.csv` and `DF_TripHeader_2018-12-05.csv`. Sadly I cant send you the content since it contains customer data.

Edit: Exchanged double backslashes through forward slashes.

Comment: Don't you think values in the `Queries = {"DF_TripHeader":DF_TripHeader,"DF_AM":DF_AM}` should have been strings. like `Queries = {"DF_TripHeader": 'DF_TripHeader',"DF_AM":'DF_AM'}` ?

Comment: No they are Variables, their content is the query code.
But I just tested some thing: when I do this `for filename in glob.glob("C:/Users/micha/PycharmProjects/Jivana_Driver_Analysis/SQL_RawData/*"):` everything works perfectly but when I write `for filename in glob.glob('"C:/Users/micha/PycharmProjects/Jivana_Driver_Analysis/' + SQL_Folder + '*"'):` it doesnt work. Maybe this helps.

Comment: ok, you need to use format function like `glob.glob("C:/Users/micha/PycharmProjects/Jivana_Driver_Analysis/{0}*".format( SQL_Folder))` to avoid mulstring formation.

Comment: this works perfectly. thank you so much! is there a way that I can leave away the whole path so it works on other computers too? I will put my updated code in an edit, once again thank you so much!

Comment: yes, you can do that, just make proper use of `format` function.

Comment: aaaaand done! edited the code again, works like a charm now!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184758/discussion-between-micha-brugger-and-kishor-pawar).