# Delete all files in a directory with a similar name?

Tags: python, python-2.7

so I am currently somewhat new in python, usually, I do programming in Node.js. I wanted to know if there is a way to delete all files that has a specific name in them?

For example, let's say I have the following files in a directory:

```
PDforeg.txt
PDahvn.txt
AHgme.txt
Ronra.txt
```

I want to be able to delete all files that *includes* the word "PD" in them. How do I do this?

Comment: There are many ways. What have you tried? Did you search for anything already? Did you try something that didn't work?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012670/deleting-files-which-start-with-a-name-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import glob
import os

files = glob.glob("PATH_to_directory/*.txt")

for file in files:
    if "PD" in file:
        os.remove(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('rm *PD*.txt', shell=True)
```

---

Or you could import os and do os.remove() stuff.

Answer (score 0):

For multi platform you can use the following script:

```
import glob
import os
folder = '/home/user/Documents/'
text_to_look_for = 'PD'
for f in glob.glob(folder + '*' + text_to_look_for +'*.txt'):
     os.remove(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pathlib
path = pathlib.Path('D:/dev/stackoverflow') # This is your folder

[p.unlink() for p in path.glob('*PD*')]

# Another way of writing the above line
for p in path.glob('*PD*'):
    p.unlink()
```

`*PD*` will be all files that have PD in them somewhere, not just at the start. If you want to remove files with `PD` only at the start, use `PD*`.

Answer (score -1):

In bash, just,

```
[user ~]$rm *.txt
```

This command will delete all the files with the same .txt extension in the current directory.

Comment: That's both not what is asked for nor the appropriate language...